# To show that $\mathbb{F}_2/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> If $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a finite field with two elements than show that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Now $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle (x+1) (x+1)\rangle$

Now I know that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x+1\rangle=\mathbb{F}_2$.

I need help understanding the quotient $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: Every coset of $(x^2+1)$ in ${\bf F}_2[x]$ is of the form $ax+b+(x^2+1)$ for $a,b$ in ${\bf F}_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is in $F^2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, then by euclidean division by $x^2+1$, you get that $P$ is of the forme $ax+b$.

And reciprocally, every $Q=ax+b$ gives you a different element of $F^2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Since $\{ax+b,\ a,b\in \mathbb F_2\}$ is a vector space of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb F_2$, you have your result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle g\rangle$, where $\mathbb F$ is a field and $g\in{\mathbb F}[x]$ a polynomial of degree $\geq 1$.
By division with remainder, for each polynomial $f$ we have
$$f = q\cdot g + r$$
where $q,r$ are polynomials with either $r=0$ or degree of $r<$ degree of $g$.
It can be shown that the residue classes $[f]$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the polynomials $f$ with degree smaller than the degree of $g$. Thus $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle g\rangle = \{[f]\mid \mbox{degree of $f<$ degree of $g$}\}$. Then $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle g\rangle$ is an $\mathbb F$-algebra and in particular a $\mathbb F$-vector space with basis $\{[1],[x],\ldots,[x^{m-1}]\}$ where $m$ is the degree of $g$.